# $window.history.pushState throws error when $location present

Tags: angularjs

Here is a plunkr that shows my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/c0AEXBXAHz4ZqH4kIXyN. $window.history.pushState throws an error when $location is present in the dependency injector and you pass a non-empty string as the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not worry about tackling with HTML5 history via `pushState` since [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) service does it behind scene for you.

> In HTML5 mode, the $location service getters and setters interact with
>   the browser URL address through the HTML5 history API, which allows
>   for use of regular URL path and search segments, instead of their
>   hashbang equivalents.

What you need is just enable the HTML5 mode like what you did `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`.

Comment: ah, you're right. What I really needed was to set {reloadOnSearch: false} on my route.